# phpMyAdmin - can I export an "alter table" query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I add a few fields in a table and want to quickly modify the same table in different database - so I want phpMyAdmin to generate the alter table query for selected fields. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can play with information_schema.

```
select concat('alter table ',table_schema,'.',table_name, '.....;')
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

Then you can run all the queries.

Comment: This doesn't provide the datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with phpmyadmin, But you can use a tool like [heidisql](http://www.heidisql.com/)(windows desktop application) where it displays all the sql it runs when you do changes using the gui. You can copy this sql and run it in other dbs.

Comment: Yeah I can get the LAST query run from phpMyAdmin but was hoping I was missing a GUI features somewhere.